# さくらサーバーのhtaccessでhttpsを検知するには

Tags: .htaccess

ここで聞くことではないかもしれませんが。

さくらサーバーで独自sslを導入しておりhttps統一かつwwwありで統一したいと思っており、htaccessでリダイレクトを記述しています。

httpからhttpsにリダイレクトする際には

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

と、さくらサーバーの仕様上、`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} ^$` を使わないと行けないとのことで、これは実現できました。

しかしながら、www付を行うとリダイレクトループになります。

```
https://sample.com
から
https://www.sample.com
```

にリダイレクトするとダイレクトループになります。

httpからhttpsへのも通常のリダイレクトをやるとループになりますが、`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For}` をつけるとループにならず、
じゃあwww付きの時にもコレを適用すればいいかというと、もとからhttpsアクセスの場合は変数が代わるようでfalseが帰るようです。

さくらサーバーで

```
https://sample.com
から
https://www.sample.com
```

へのリダイレクトのためのhtaccessの記述がお分かりでしたお教えください。

Answer (score 4):

さくらのレンタルサーバーでSNI SSLを使う場合、
ドメインの設定を「マルチドメインとして使用する（推奨）」で設定してしまうと、
httpsでの接続時、「wwwなし」「wwwあり」どちらでアクセスしても
ヘッダーのHTTP_HOSTは、両方とも 「sample.com」を返してきますので、
これがループの原因となります。

これを回避するには、「wwwなし」「wwwあり」を別のドメインとして登録し、
それぞれのドメインを「wwwを付与せずマルチドメインとして使用する（上級者向け）」に設定して、
別々のフォルダを指定します。

SSL証明書は1つの証明書で「wwwなし」「wwwあり」どちらでも有効ですので、両方に設定します。
※片方に登録してから「秘密鍵のバックアップ」をクリックして秘密鍵をダウンロードし、会員メニューの契約情報から「SSL証明書」をダウンロードします。
これをもう片方のドメイン設定に登録します。

wwwなしの.htaccessは下記のようにします。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

wwwありの.htaccessは下記のようにします。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

下記も参考になれば幸いです。
http://qiita.com/aniya/items/664491b523fe6c717b13

Answer (score 1):

「httpsアクセスの場合は変数が代わるようでfalseが返る」のであれば、X-Sakura-Forwarded-For が空じゃない、かつ、HTTP_HOST が www.sample.com ではない場合にリダイレクトするルールセットを追加すればいいと思います。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} ^on$
#   %{ENV:HTTPS} は不要？
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.sample.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```